# Conditional probability equations with OR

Tags: probability, propositional-calculus

I have to calculate

$$P(\text{Cavity} \mid \neg \text{tooth} \vee \neg \text{catch})$$

I have a table with probabilties

Now i've done it this way

$$\frac{P(\text{Cavity}, \neg \text{tooth} \vee \neg \text{catch})}{P(\neg \text{tooth} \vee \neg \text{catch})}$$

I've then done my calculations this way

$$P(\text {Cavity}, \neg \text{tooth} \vee \neg \text{catch})=P(\text{Cavity}, \neg \text{tooth})+P(\text{Cavity}, \neg \text{catch}) $$
And $$P(\neg \text{tooth} \vee \neg \text{catch}) = P(\neg \text{tooth})+P(\neg \text{catch})$$

Is this the right way? I've probably done it wrong. Can someone give me an advice? Thanks

Comment: Remember $P(A | B) = P(A \wedge B)/P(B)$. In this case $B$ is the event "not tooth or not catch = not(tooth and catch)," so the numerator is $P(Cavity, \lnot (\text{tooth, catch}))$.

Comment: P(Cavity,¬(tooth, catch)) isn't this the same as my equation?

Comment: Yes, sorry must have misread your first equation (unless you edited it). Your next equations are only valid if the events $\lnot \text{tooth}$ and $\lnot \text{catch}$ are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Nah I've edited my post in the time you wrote your comment.   What does "mutually exclusive" mean?  At the moment i took all the probabilities where (cavity, not tooth) holds added these and same for (cavity, not catch) I added every prob only 1 time. I guess that's the mutually not exclusive case. But shouldn't I take care of this by only taking each proabability 1 time?

Comment: Two events $ A,B\ $ are mutually exclusive if $\ P(A\wedge B)=0\ $—that is, it is impossible for both of them to occur together.  In general, $\ P(A\vee B)=$$P(A)\, +$$ P(B)\ -$$P(A\wedge B)\ $ and this is equal to $\ P(A) \ +$$ P(B)\ $ if and only if $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are mutually exclusive.